# Readability: list iteration with get_first/get_next, "while" vs. "for" loop

Tags: for-loop, while-loop, readability

Let's say you would like to iterate trough a list using an initial get_first() with subsequent calls to get_next() which returns NULL at the end of the list.

Which one would you prefer reading?

```
element = get_first(list);
while (element)
{
    process(element);
    element = get_next(list);
}
```

vs.

```
for (element = get_first(list); element; element = get_next(list))
{
    process(element);
}
```

The state of an iteration is saved inside the list struct.

I am personally more used to the `while` version but when I saw someone use the `for` version I also easily understood what was going on so now I wonder which one is easier to read for most people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are very readable. You won't confuse your readers with either. The while loop is arguably a bit more readable (But people mileage may vary...) so I would probably use it if the list was only iterated over once and use the more concise for loop otherwise.